# Returning entry from an array that fits a range condition

Tags: excel-2007

Is there a way to have a cell in Excel 2007 view through an array of six numbers and return the highest of any of the numbers that fit into a specified range?

My particular numbers in the array are `22 18 14 10 7 4` and my range is `6 to 12`. I was thinking of creating a separate column with the AND function to simplify some steps but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are referring to when you say array, but if the array refers to cells:

```
{=MAX(IF(B18:G18<12,IF(B18:G18>6,B18:G18,0),0))}
```

Will give you the value between (6,12) which is highest in the range A1:A6.

Be sure to make the function an array wise function by using `control + shift + enter`.